# Is it possible to match two women to each man so that every women will not match more than once

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, matching-theory

I am new to this topic and I have no idea how to proceed.
Any help ?

Given a group of men and group of women.
Every group of man $A$, $|A|$=$x$ knows a group of women $B$ and the cardinality of $B$ is at least $2x$.
Prove that it is possible to match two women to each man so that every women will not match more than once.

Thank you

Comment: This all sounds rather sexist. Anyway split each man into two....

Comment: It appears that English is not your first language, and it's quite tough to understand your question as written. You can click "Edit" beneath your question and type in something like "In Greek[or whatever your language is], what I'm asking is: ...." and then type your question in Greek[or whatever language]. With luck, someone who knows Greek can answer, or can perhaps translate more clearly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Clone each man so that you will have the same number of man and woman.
- Use Hall's marriage theorem.